# love2d - love.physics/ love.body/ grid

Tags: lua, game-engine, game-physics, love2d

Hello I'm playing around with Lua/Love2D and I want to know if it's possible to Use a grid and love.body together. I wanted to make and test out grids and I also want to make a world = love.physics.newWorld to set the gravity 0, 0 and use love.body:applyForce to give it a space like feeling.

So right now I have player

```
<code>
  player = {}
    player.gridx = 64
player.gridy = 64
player.acty = 200
player.speed = 32
</code>
```

Because I'm using grid but I would also like to add

```
  <code>
world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 0, true)

   In   love.load()
  </code>
```

And then in player class

```
 <code>
 player = {}
  player.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 550, "dynamic")
  player.body:setMass(100) -- make it pretty light
  player.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 30, 15)
  player.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(player.body, player.shape, 2) 
  player.fixture:setRestitution(0.4)    -- make it bouncy
</code>
```

and then use

```
<code>
 if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
 player.body:applyForce(10, 0.0)
 print("moving right")
 elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
 player.body:applyForce(-10, 0.0)
 print("moving left")
 end
if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
player.body:applyForce(0, -500)
elseif love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
player.body:applyForce(0, 100)
end
</code>
```

Instead of

```
<code>
  function love.keypressed(key)

  if key == "up" then
    if testMap(0, -1) then
        player.gridy = player.gridy - 32
    end
 elseif key == "down" then
    if testMap(0, 1) then
        player.gridy = player.gridy + 32
     end
   elseif key == "left" then
    if testMap(-1, 0) then
        player.gridx = player.gridx - 32
    end
  elseif key == "right" then
    if testMap(1, 0) then
        player.gridx = player.gridx + 32
    end
  end
 end
</code>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you can't do. Are you saying you want to use the Box2d physics but only move onto discreet grid locations? Or something else

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can!

I get the feeling what you want is to display a body (in this case, your player sprite) that's affected by physics?

If so, in your love.draw block simply use player.body.getY() and player.body.getY() when drawing your quad/grid.

Ex:

```
function love.draw()
     love.graphics.circle( "fill", player.body:getX(), player.body:getY(), 50, 100 )
```

Would draw a ball on the screen that is affected by the physics engine.

Alternatively you may be asking about world coordinate translation.  ie: You want to say 64, 64 instead of using the BOX2D coordinates, in which case look to the getWorldPoint method:

(https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Body:getWorldPoint)